# How can I get User confirm on combobox change event in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, callback, client-side

I have a combo in my extjs application and I want to show 'Are you 
sure?' confirm window to the user and prevent changing if user said no.

Since JavaScript's confirm box is synchronous, it works properly. But using Ext JS, the confirmation message is shown, and the rest of my code would be executed before user responds. Here is my code:

```
// JavaScript confirm box
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    listeners: {
        beforeselect: function(combo, record, index ) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure ?') == false)
            {
                 return false; // prevent combo from changing
            }
            // else continue
        }
    }
}
// Ext JS message box (to confirm)
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    listeners: {
        beforeselect: function(combo, record, index ) {
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Warning',
                msg: 'Are You Sure ?',
                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                fn: function(btn) {
                    if (btn == 'yes') {
                        // continue and set new value on combo
                    }
                    else if (btn == 'no') {
                        // prevent combo from changing
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the `Ext.Msg.show` gets a callback function and is not waiting for user answer and we're not able to prevent combobox changing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

In order to cancel the combobox change, the `beforeSelect` listener needs to return false. My suggestion is:

```
beforeselect: function(combo, record, index ) {
  Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Warning',
    msg: 'Are You Sure ?',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
    fn: function(btn) {
      if (btn == 'yes') {

        // Here we have to manually set the combo value
        // since the original select event was cancelled
        combo.setValue( /* whatever value was selected */ );
      }

      else if (btn == 'no') {

        // Don't do anything because the select event was already cancelled
      }
    }
  });

  // Cancel the default action
  return false;
}
```

The ExtJS Modal does not halt execution of the script like the native dialog, which means that the `beforeSelect` listener was returning prior to the user action. The way this code works is that the select event is immediately stopped, and the dialog shown. When the user selects "yes", then the value on the combo is programmatically set in the callback function.

Comment: that's not work, because in beforeselect we don't know the new selected value yet!

Comment: Please think and then answer

Comment: You do know the selected value in `beforeselect` it is the second argument (record in the guy's answer above). To get the value you can use `record.get([the combos value field]);`

Comment: Worked for me +1 ! If you are using custom alert view then there are chances that it may get visible before combolist gets collapsed, In that case use `combo.collapse( )`